# Can default_scope be within an if block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wanted to know if I can put `default_scope` inside an if block. I have a User model that `has_one` profile. This is the code I have in my User model:

```
Class User

default_scope joins(:profile).order('profiles.updated_at DESC').readonly(false)

end
```

The issue is that when the database has no profiles created it gives an error, since profiles are nil. Can I use an if block where I can say:

```
unless self.profile.nil?
 default_scope joins(:profile).order('profiles.updated_at DESC').readonly(false)
end
```

Are there any alternatives to this approach?

Comment: the issue is not in the `default_scope`, it is somewhere else in your code.  even if you don't have any profile in the db, that should not cause any error.

Comment: a scope is at the class level

Comment: Ok so, it doesnt matter if there are any profiles in the db or not. If i have the above code in my User model, it is clashing with Devise. Specifically Devise confirmable. After confirming, it doesnt direct me to the User Show page. I guess I am providing enough info. But anyone experience this issue?

Comment: Seems like you'd want to use `include` rather than `joins`. Since you don't always have a profile you end up limiting the results, which isn't the purpose of the scope. I wonder if that would also fix the error you're getting.

Comment: Tom L, you solved the mystery. Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I see in the comments that you've already solved your problem, here's an answer to the question you actually asked, in case someone else comes across this and wonders:

Technically, yes, you can place the `default_scope` call within an `if` block. **However**, that conditional will be tested (and the `default_scope` applied or not) *when the class is loaded*. Meaning when you start the application (or when the request is sent, in development mode). You wouldn't be able to examine the properties of a particular instance of the class, because that instance doesn't exist yet.

Short version: a `default_scope` will either apply to all queries based on the model, or none of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do something like this:

```
default_scope lambda {
  unless profile.nil?
    joins(:profile).order('profiles.updated_at DESC').readonly(false)
  end
}
```

Here is [an example](https://github.com/railsdog/spree_landlord/blob/9369ddae0731de65c81a4cff4ec53a2224cfd6b9/app/models/spree/option_type_decorator.rb) from the spree_landlord project.